# Getting "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol" exception on a valid url string?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to write an android app in kotlin that downloads an mp3 file over the web. The code where the problem happens is as follows:

```
fun downloadAudio(url: String, f: File) {
    Log.d(JOURNAL_FETCHR_TAG, "URL is $url")
    val iStream: InputStream = URL(url).openStream() // EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE
    val oStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(f)
    var buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var len = iStream.read(buffer)

    while (len > 0) {
        oStream.write(buffer, 0, len)
        len = iStream.read(buffer)
    }
    oStream.close()
}
```

I am getting the following exception on the line above:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[DownloadIntentService]
                  Process: com.sarpuner.journal, PID: 23301
                  java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: "http://telechargement.rfi.fr/rfi/francais/audio/jff/201808/journal_francais_facile_20h00_-_20h10_tu_20180819.mp3"
                      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:601)
                      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:498)
                      at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:447)
                      at com.sarpuner.journal.JournalFetchrKt.downloadAudio(JournalFetchr.kt:78)
                      at com.sarpuner.journal.DownloadIntentService.onHandleIntent(DownloadIntentService.kt:24)
                      at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:76)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

The url seems fine though, so I can't figure out the reason for the error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're somehow ending up with parentheses in `url`. That Exception message prints the URL string bare. That is, if it didn't have extraneous parens, it would've printed `no protocol: http://...`.

Comment: I'd say @MikeM. is correct - except I believe he meant "extraneous double-quotes".  Maybe include the Log.d output as well to confirm.

Comment: @Andy Oh, jeez, yeah. Duh. Quotes, I meant. Been a long day, I guess.

Comment: Thank you so much, the Log.d output is `D/JournalFetchr: URL is "http://telechargement.rfi.fr/rfi/francais/audio/jff/201808/journal_francais_facile_20h00_-_20h10_tu_20180819.mp3"`

Comment: Yep, extra quotes. Work backwards from `downloadAudio()` to figure out where they're coming from.

Comment: Thank you so so much, I have been trying to figure this out for a while now.